# How can I determine the expected value / risk of ruin of game where probability changes dependent on state?

Tags: probability, markov-process

Consider the following game:

You are given a random number generator which you can use to play a game. The object of the game is to reach the final tier after which you collect prize tokens. In order to reach the final tier, you must roll the RNG and pass a specific level for each tier. Each time you roll, you either pass or fail. However, on the final two tiers you have a chance of dropping down one tier if you fail. Here is the corresponding table of tiers with percentage chance of each outcome:

[image: Tier Table]

1. Success = Move up 1 Tier
2. Failure = Nothing Happens
3. Drop Down = Fail and Move Down a Tier

Assume that you start the game on tier 1 with 1000 tokens. Each roll, regardless of tier, costs 30 tokens. When you succeed on tier 5, you win 1000 tokens and return to tier 1.

Question:

1. How do you determine the expected value (EV) of each roll?
2. How do you calculate the risk of ruin of this game?